# Anti-swear system blacklisting non-swear words

Tags: python, parsing, discord, discord.py

Basically, I have an anti-swear system in my Discord bot, and one of the blacklisted words is "hoe". But if you say a word that contains a swear word, for example  "w**hoe**ver" the bot will detect that as a swear word, since it finds the word "hoe" in it.

How do I prevent this from happening without removing the word "hoe" from the blacklist?

Here's my code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    for badword in file:
        if badword in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            warnMessage = f"Hey {message.author.mention}! Don't say that!"
            await message.channel.send(warnMessage, delete_after=5.0)
            print(f"{message.author.name} tried saying: {badword}")
            channel = client.get_channel(836232733126426666)
            
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Someone tried to swear!", colour=0x2D2D2D)
            embed.add_field(name="Person who tried to swear:", value=f"{message.author.name}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="What they tried to say:", value=f"{badword}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Channel they tried to swear in:", value=f"<#{message.channel.id}>", inline=False)
            
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            return
            await client.process_commands(message)
            
    if message.content.startswith('Jason derulo'):
        await message.channel.send('Wiggle wiggle wiggle')
        
    if message.content.startswith('fast'):
        await message.channel.send('She a runner she a track star')
    await client.process_commands(message)
    
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    for badword in file:
        if badword in after.content.lower():
            await after.delete()
            warnMessage = f"Hey {after.author.mention}! Don't say that!\n*You said ||{badword}||*"
            await after.channel.send(warnMessage, delete_after=5.0)
            print(f"{message.author.name} tried saying: {badword}")
            channel = client.get_channel(836232733126426666)
            
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Someone tried to swear!", colour=0x2D2D2D)
            embed.add_field(name="Person who tried to swear:", value=f"{message.author.name}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="What they tried to say:", value=f"{badword}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Channel they tried to swear in:", value=f"<#{message.channel.id}>", inline=False)
            
            return await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You can change your list to include a space before and after, but that won't catch quotes or commas.  The only safe way is to have a function look for the word using `s.find`, and if found, check the characters before and after to make sure they're not alphabetic.

Comment: If you're interested in this problem, there's a lot of info on its [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe).

Comment: You're going to want to explore [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: Presuming that `file` is the (poorly-named) repository of forbidden words, you can check the words in a message against that by parsing out words from the message (e.g. into `mess_word`) and checking them in turn, `if mess_word in file` etc.

Comment: Here's an explanation as to why [web filters don't work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcZdwX4noCE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about people trying to obfuscate the words to get past your system e.g. `eeHOEee`, you could use `.split(' ')` to create an list of all of the words in the contents. Then you can check the list to see if a 'badword' is found.

```
message_content_list = (message.content.lower()).split(' ')
for badword in file:
    if badword in message_content_list:
```

Just realised, but since you're iterating over a number of different words, to optimize the code a bit you can do:

```
message_content_set = set((message.content.lower()).split(' '))
for badword in file:
        if badword in message_content_set:
```

This should speed up the process a bit, as checking if an item is `in` a set is faster than checking a list.

*Note: the difference in runtime would be very minimal, and normally you wouldn't do this unless there are a large number of 'bad words' to iterate over.*

Comment: is there a way I can make a whitelist just for like a few words?

Comment: For sure. use a loop to iterate over the message, then do `if word not in goodwords:` @Ender2K89